# Radio button shuffling in android

Tags: android, radio-button, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle radio button in android, here's is the code what i have done till now, but as I proceed further I am not getting what should be the code or how to do that.

Please correct if I am wrong, or doing some silly mistake as I am new to it.

```
ArrayList<RadioButton> arrayText = new ArrayList<>(); 

arrayText.add(ropt0); 
arrayText.add(ropt1); 
arrayText.add(ropt2); 
arrayText.add(ranswer); 

Collections.shuffle(arrayText);
```

I am not getting what next after `Collections.shuffle(arrayText);`
should be the code

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't quite understand what are you doing and what do you want. In your code you just adding all your `RadioButtons` to `ArrayList` and then shuffle this list. This is same as:

```
ArrayList<Stirng> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a1");
list.add("a2");

Collections.shuffle(list);
```

You see, this isn't connected to UI in any way. If you want to shuffle buttons in UI (so user will see it) you have 2 approaches:

1. Create and add your radio buttons in the code. Define some `RadioGroup` in view XML file and then create and add your `RadioButton`s

   ```
   RadioGroup lay = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_radio_group);
   List<RadioButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
   RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton(this);
   RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton(this);
   buttons.add(rb1);
   buttons.add(rb2);
   Collections.shuffle(buttons);
   for(RadioButton rb:
       buttons){
       lay.addView(rb,new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
   }
   ```
2. Shuffle just a right button position. Create `N` buttons in XML. And then set all texts in your code, so you can decide which button is the right one.

   ```
   List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>(4); // 4 - button number
   //Fill the list here
   int rightAnswerPosition = ...; //Decide it when you fill your list
   rb1.setText(answers.get(0));
   //.. and so on
   ```